# Map nested array to render in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a nested array object in my project. Here's the array i have :

```js
const listItem = [
    {name:'Patrick star',id:"1",costs:[{name:'Read Book'},{name:'Drink water'}]},
    {name:'Gallileo',id:"2",costs:[{name:'Read Book'},{name:'Drink water'},,{name:'Walking'}]},
    {name:'Einsten',id:"3",costs:[{name:'Read Book'},{name:'Drink water'}]},
    {name:'Peterson',id:"4",costs:[{name:'Read Book'},{name:'Drink water'}]},
    {name:'Schwarzenneger',id:"5",costs:[{name:'Read Book'},{name:'Drink water'}]},
    {name:'Dostoyevsky',id:"6",costs:[{name:'Read Book'},{name:'Drink water'}]}
]
```

Now, i am rendering this in my project. The names are showing fine but i can't add the `costs` by maping. Here's what i have reached to :

```js
 <FlatList
    style={{marginTop:10}}
    data={listItem}
    renderItem={({item})=>(
    <View style={{justifyContent:'center',marginBottom:10}}>
      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        {listItem.map((u,i) => {
            return (
                <Text>{u.costs[i].name}</Text> //this line throws error
            )
        })
        }
    </View>
    )}
 />
```

I might have done something wrong with the mapping.

Comment: Use `u.name` instead of `u.costs[i].name`, If you are trying to display the `name` of `listItem`. If you want to display both `name` and cost name, you have to use two `array#map`.

Comment: I want the names from the costs array not the other one. @HassanImam

Comment: can you show me how can i get costs names @HassanImam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to map your costs instead of listItem:

```
<FlatList
    style={{marginTop:10}}
    data={listItem}
    renderItem={({item})=>(
    <View style={{justifyContent:'center',marginBottom:10}}>
      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        {item.costs.map(cost => {
            return (
                <Text>{cost.name}</Text>
            )
        })
        }
    </View>
    )}
 />
```